# Calling forward() on DataStream prior sinking to Kafka topic

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

## Environment

Flink = `v1.14.0`

## Scenario

1. Source data from Kafka.
2. Source extra data via HTTP and broadcast it.
3. Combine data from 1st and 2nd datasources via `CoProcessFunction`
4. Sink to Kafka via `KafkaSink` of resulting DataStream from previous step.
5. Job restarted
6. All records from 4th are re-sent to Kafka Topic, since `AT_LEAST_ONCE` strategy used. It results to duplicates of records in Kafka topic, hence results to incorrect further data transmitting/analysis/*whatever*.

Usage of `EXACTLY_ONCE` strategy for KafkaSink does not suite well for our case.

## Suggested solution

Prior sinking DataStream from 4th step to Kafka - I've decided to call `forward()` method on `DataStream<MyAwesomeObject>` *(Well, just found this method in source code)*

**Before**:

```
...
myDataStream.sinkTo(preConfiguredKafkaSink)
...
```

**After**:

```
...
myDataStream.forward().sinkTo(preConfiguredKafkaSink)...
...
```

Adding `forward()` call on DataStream seems like solves the problem:

- Job restarted.
- Sources are reinitialised.
- KafkaSink is reinitialised as well.
- No duplicates record in topic.

Any cons/pros on calling `forward()` prior calling `sinkTo(...)`?

Comment: Calling `.forward()` shouldn't change anything as far as whether or not you get duplicate records when you have to replay source records following a restore from a checkpoint.

Comment: No problem with source. Issue occurs with sink only.

Comment: Replayed(Re-sent) records is data inside KafkaSink which was checkpointed.
So, once job restarted, let say, due to one of taskmanagers was restarted - all data from checkpoint restored to state and sunk again.   

Just went through more source code - `forward()` call on DataStream sets `ForwardPartitioner` on stream...But looking deeper - this is default partitioner for DataStream.   

At the moment I'm failing to answer - why explicit partitioner assignment differs from default one in terms of restoring state from checkpoint for KafkaSinks.

Comment: just to be clear, when a Flink job is restored from checkpoint, the duplicate data you see flowing to the sink is data that is being re-played from the Kafka source, starting from the partition offsets that were restored from the last checkpoint. This is true regardless of whether you're running with AT_LEAST_ONCE or EXACTLY_ONCE checkpointing mode.

Comment: @kkrugler at the moment issue does not occur any more… I understand your point. But in our case behavior was strange, since in kafka sources there was retention period for records for 1h and issue occurred after month of data processing…maybe some issues on kafka source side.